# Laravel: Install Microsoft Azure Client Library with composer

Tags: php, azure, laravel-5, composer-php

Does anyone installed Microsoft Azure Client Library to a Laravel 5 project with composer on an Ubuntu server?

When I try to install with Composer (command: composer require microsoft/windowsazure), I got the next error:

```
Using version ^0.4.1 for microsoft/windowsazure
./composer.json has been updated
> php artisan clear-compiled
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for microsoft/windowsazure ^0.4.1 -> satisfiable by microsoft/windowsazure[v0.4.1].
- microsoft/windowsazure v0.4.1 requires pear-pear2.php.net/http_request2 * -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by modifying the config of the composer, by setting the secure-http to false

```
"config": {
    "secure-http": "false"
}
```